# How to limit the selection of the first level block in Gutenberg editor

Tags: block-editor

I have my own custom block with an `InnerBlock` component which is kind of a **container** for the contents of each section in the document.

The whole process of adding content always starts with adding this block.
Therefore, I would like to **limit the selection of first level blocks to only this one block.**

Once the user has added this block, then he can add other blocks inside.

This is a question without a code example as I have no idea where to start. I've seen an idea like templates, but that's not appropriate in this case.

**Goal to be achieved (in simple words):**

- the user creates a new post
- can only select one specific block
- only in this block he can select other available blocks
- it can happen multiple times in one post

Answer (score 0):

Create a new custom block, lets call it `CustomSecondary`, that contains an `InnerBlocks` instance.

When registering this block set it's [parent property to your main custom block](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/block-api/block-registration/#parent-optional) and

```
registerBlockType(
    'custom-secondary',
    {
        parent: ['your-main-block],
        edit: () => ( <InnerBlocks />)
        { .. your other properties }
    });
```

This will make it so this block can only be inserted into your main block.

In the `edit` property of your main block add the [`allowedBlocks`](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/tutorials/block-tutorial/nested-blocks-inner-blocks/#allowed-blocks) props to your `InnerBlocks` instance and only allow your `custom-secondary` block

`<InnerBlocks allowedBlocks={[ 'custom-secondary' ]} />`

Now when you insert, you'll only have that option and then the `custom-secondary` can have any blocks you want inside.

To control the template for the post it self, you can add the [following filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/block-api/block-templates/#api):

```
function myplugin_register_template() {
    $post_type_object = get_post_type_object( 'post' );
    $post_type_object->template = array(
        array( 'core/image' ),
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'myplugin_register_template' );
```

You might want to consider using locked template with a single block that can have items inserted into it.

Comment: This way, you can still add any core block first - and that's not what we want. The first block selection must be limited to my custom block only. Then inside my block you should be able to add any block (core or custom)

Comment: That's what this example does. The first block has the allowsBlocks attribute - which dictates what blocks can be placed inside it.

Comment: We have a little misunderstanding. When adding a new post, you still have access to all the core blocks at the very beginning. E.g you can click the plus icon (next to reno/undo icons) and there you still have all the core blocks and you can use them. They shouldn't be available at first. Access should only be inside my custom block

Comment: I updated the answer to include editing the templat